# How to run 'connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec' as root in python k8s client

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

```
from os import getenv, listdir, path
from kubernetes import client, config
from kubernetes.stream import stream
import constants, logging
from pprint import pprint

def listdir_fullpath(directory):
    return [path.join(directory, file) for file in listdir(directory)]

def active_context(kubeConfig, cluster):
    config.load_kube_config(config_file=kubeConfig, context=cluster)

def kube_exec(command, apiInstance, podName, namespace, container):
    response = None
    execCommand = [
        '/bin/bash',
        '-c',
        command]
    try:
        response = apiInstance.read_namespaced_pod(name=podName,
                                                namespace=namespace)
    except ApiException as e:
        if e.status != 404:
            print(f"Unknown error: {e}")
            exit(1)
    if not response:
        print("Pod does not exist")
        exit(1)
    try:
        response = stream(apiInstance.connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec,
                          podName,
                          namespace,
                          container=container,
                          command=execCommand,
                          stderr=True,
                          stdin=False,
                          stdout=True,
                          tty=False,
                          _preload_content=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print("error in executing cmd")
        exit(1)
    pprint(response)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    configPath     = constants.CONFIGFILE
    kubeConfigList = listdir_fullpath(configPath)
    kubeConfig = ':'.join(kubeConfigList)
    active_context(kubeConfig, "ort.us-west-2.k8s.company-foo.net")
    apiInstance = client.CoreV1Api()
    kube_exec("whoami", apiInstance, "podname-foo", "namespace-foo", "container-foo")
```

I run this code
and the response I get from running `whoami` is:`'java\n'`
how can I run as root? also, I can't find a good doc for this client anywhere (the docs on the git repo are pretty horrible) if you can link me to any it would be awesome

EDIT: I just tried on a couple of different pods and containers, looks like some of them default to root, would still like to be able to choose my user when I run a command so question is still relevant

Answer (score 1):

> some of them default to root, would still like to be able to choose my user when I run a command so question is still relevant

You have influence over the UID (not the user directly, as far as I know) when you *launch* the Pod, but from that point forward, there is no equivalent to `docker exec -u` in kubernetes -- you can attach to the Pod, running as whatever UID it was launched as, but you cannot change the UID

I would hypothesize that's a security concern in locked down clusters, since one would not want someone with kubectl access to be able to elevate privileges

If you need to run as `root` in your container, then you should change the value of [`securityContext: runAsUser: 0`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod) and then drop privileges for running your main process. That way new commands (spawned by your `exec` command) will run as root, just as your initial `command:` does